# problems importing tensorflow

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I'm working on a project using keras (python 3), and I've encountered a problem - I've installed using pip tensorflow, and imported it into my prject, but whenether I try to run it, I get an error saying:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'
```

it seems my installation completed successfully, and I think I have the right PATH since I installed few other things such as numpy and their installation worked well. does anyone have a clue what did I do wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: First create  a separate environment (use virtualenv or anaconda). Then install tensorflow inside that environment. If you try running tensorflow like this, you could be rest assured that something else is not acting as a source of trouble. Also, since you installed with pip, check availability of tensorflow in the list of installed libraries by running `pip freeze` command.

Comment: @CypherX thank you for your reply. I followed all the necessary steps but unfortunately, It didn't work. perhaps the problem is the PATH and I'm wrong? how can I make sure the path is correct?

Comment: Did you find `tensorflow` in `pip freeze` output?

Comment: @CypherX yes I did

Comment: What is the `pip freeze` output for `tensorflow`? (give the whole line)

Comment: @CypherX 

tensorboard==1.14.0
tensorflow==1.14.0
tensorflow-estimator==1.14.0

and once again, thank you for your help

Comment: Great. So, now startup a jupyter notebook and do `!pip freeze` and see if you can find `tensorflow` in the output. If you use anaconda, also check which enviroment you are in with `conda env list`. You must start the jupyter notebook from the environment where you installed tensorflow.

Comment: @CypherX, I've tried to install using anadconda3 and also through windows cmd,

when I check anaconda env. I get this:

# conda environments:
#
base                  *  C:\Users\elinor\Anaconda3
tf                       C:\Users\elinor\Anaconda3\envs\tf
tf-3                     C:\Users\elinor\Anaconda3\envs\tf-3
tfenv                    C:\Users\elinor\Anaconda3\envs\tfenv

it's not where my project is... how should I move it there?

and when I check jupyter notebook I couldn't find tensorflow in the output. could you please guide me what should I do from here? thank you!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200117/discussion-between-e-ginzburg-and-cypherx).

Answer (score 1):

secondary create backup for itenary such as vm

Answer (score 1):

Faced similar issue when installing Tensorflow, following might the reasons:

- Installing IDLE before Anaconda.
- Incorrect path variable while installing.

  **Solution for this is**,
- Uninstall Anaconda and IDLE(if installed)
- Setup Anaconda and add path variable while installing
- Create environment in conda prompt `conda create -n env_name python=3.7`
- Activate environment `conda activate env_name`
- Install Pandas, Tensorflow and Keras. (Other required libraries come with env)